# How do I profile stored procedures on Oracle?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, profiler

There is an Oracle DB to which I have access. I can view its packages using Aqua Data Studio and make queries to it. I don't have any access to the filesystem of the server.

There is also a binary that uses that database by calling stored procedures from it.

I want to know which stored procedures and with what parameters are used by this binary. It seems to be impossible to do with "Statement monitor for Oracle" - it only logs direct query calls, not stored procedures.

Can it be done with built-in trace if I don't have access to the filesystem?

Is there some other tool?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DBMS_PROFILER package: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/12_tune.htm#45936

Answer (score 0):

You can try PLSQL/Developer,it support to debug your procedure step by step.

Comment: My database is called TEST and it is located on the remote server with ip-address 123.45.67.89, to which I connect with Aqua Data Studio on port 1521. How do I connect to it using PL/SQL?